# Наибольшая общая подстрока

Tags: алгоритм, c++, visual-c++

На днях отправил резюме в Яндекс. 
Откуда мне прислали задание-найти наибольшую общую подстроку. Строк не больше 10, символов в 1 строке не больше 10 000.

Я взял [наивный алгоритм](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0). Реализовал реализовал его не совсем так, как в Википедии(эффективнее).

Все отлично, он прошел 14 тестов, везде укладывался в 1 секунду. Но на 15 [тесте](http://intern.contest.yandex.ru/testsys/download-test?runId=100552&test=14), Яндекс мне ответил-результат не верен.

Формат входных данных- С начала число строк, потом эти строки.

Не пойму, в чем дело..Яндекс пишет, что все тесты верны. Я искал сторонние решения, и они выдавали мне такой же результат, что и у меня.

Вот 2 решения, которые у меня получились-"bb" и "iq". ..как бы намекая, что iq не достаточно.

И все же.. Это провал в моей логики, или в Яндекс-тестах?

```
// Яндекс B.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

//#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
const int  MAX=10000;
char** _strings=new char*[10];
int len;

char* GetLargestCommonSubstring( char* str1, char* str2 );
inline void readNomberSubstrings();
inline const char* getMaxSubstring();

int main()
{
    readNomberSubstrings();
    cout<< getMaxSubstring();
    return 0;
}

void readNomberSubstrings()
{
    cin>>len;

    for(int i=0; i<len;i++)
        _strings[i]=new char[MAX];

    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        cin>>_strings[i];
}

 const char* getMaxSubstring()
{
    char *maxSubstring=_strings[0];
    //long T=clock();
    for(int i=1; i < len; i++)
        maxSubstring=GetLargestCommonSubstring(maxSubstring, _strings[i]);
    //cout<<clock()-T<<endl;
    return maxSubstring;
}

char* GetLargestCommonSubstring( char* str1, char* str2 ) {

    int strLen2=strlen(str2);
    const int solution_size = strLen2+ 1;

    int *x=new int[solution_size]();
    int *y= new int[solution_size]();

    int **previous = &x;
    int **current = &y;

    int max_length = 0;
    int result_index = 0;

    int j;
    int length;
    int J=strLen2 - 1;

    for(int i = strlen(str1) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for(j = J; j >= 0; j--) 
        {
            if(str1[i] != str2[j]) 
                (*current)[j] = 0;
            else 
            {
                length = 1 + (*previous)[j + 1];
                if (length > max_length)
                {
                    max_length = length;
                    result_index = i;
                }

                (*current)[j] = length;
            }
        }

        swap(previous, current);
    }
    str1[max_length+result_index]='\0';
    return &(str1[result_index]);
}
```

Comment: Думаю, вопрос "Это провал в моей логики, или в Яндекс-тестах?" можно назвать риторическим и очевидным `:)`

Comment: @Crasher, это, просто, более культурная формулировка вопрос-"Какого хрена тут происходит!?".

Comment: Вы ищите максимальное вхождение между первой и остальными строками? Может надо между любыми двумя?

Comment: @Михаил М, "Даны н строк, нужно найти их наибольшую общую подстроку."
Вот так вот в задании написано..
да и вряд ли тогда прошел бы тесты, будь настолько серьезная ошибка в логике..

Comment: а может так задумано, что последний тест должен быть провалиться? Что бы Вы подумали (проверка на стрессовые ситуации).  С другой стороны, вполне возможно, что последняя строка "нестандартная". Например, пустая.

Comment: @KoVadim, то, чем они тестирую известно-http://intern.contest.yandex.ru/testsys/download-test?runId=100552&test=14
Там нет пустых строк. Только маленький, латинские буквы. 

только правильный результат теста не известен. больше 2 символов нигде не смог найти..Хотя несколько сторонних решений(проходящих те же тесты) этой проблемы находил.

Comment: @andrw, @Chiffa, так какой ответ правильный и какое время зачетное?

--

У меня получилось **`ibm`** за 0.01 сек. на  i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz

--

А где можно прогнать программку на всех тестах?

Comment: @andrw, @Chiffa, я смог вытащить все тесты от ...test=0 до ...test=14, все уложились в 0.1 сек, 

но есть ли еще возможность узнать **правильные ответы** для каждого теста?

(по яндексу я полазил, но не нашел).

Comment: @avp, Ответ на этот тест правильный. 
У меня есть варианты только до 14 теста. И ответы, соответственно тоже. Их только найти нужно.
Как найду-отпишу сюда.

Comment: @avp,сюда результаты тестов не влезают. Напишите на почту-пришлю.
andrewvorobey77@yandex.ru

Answer (score 3):

Вижу как минимум одну ошибку: для того, чтобы вместить строку длины MAX, нужен массив размера MAX + 1. А вообще, код ужасен, я бы вас в Яндекс не взял.

Comment: @dzhioev, даже в качестве джуниора!?оО(

Comment: вообще то с++ программист должен использовать другие типы данных. А не ручками выделять память.

Comment: KoVadim, изначально я использовал vector и queue и string. Но это приводило к большим потерям времени. 
Выделяя память в ручную, я повысил эффективность более, чем в 2.5 раза.

Когда использовал стандартные решения моя программа не проходила тесты по времени.

Comment: вектор точно не хуже обычного выделенного массива.

Посмотрел код глубже. переменные `j` и `J` в соседних участках кода... это ужас.

Comment: @KoVadim, перераспределение памяти-дорого.. особенно, когда к ряду выполняется 10000*10 раз..

Поэтому и пришлось сделать одну величину для другой. 

Спасибо, что сказали, переименую.

Comment: @andrw, ну а зачем нужен джуниор, который пишет такой ужасный код? Подозреваю, что во второй функции должно быть solution_size = max(strlen(str1), strlen(str2)) + 1, но не уверен, так как код понять полностью не могу.

Comment: @dzhioev, Окей. Я так понимаю, времени у меня будет много-на работу не возьмут..) Есть время развиваться)

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как лучше развиваться?

Comment: Какой у вас возраст? Если студент, идите в ШАД.

Comment: Можно решать подобные задачи, улучшая свой код. Задачки можно взять [здесь](http://projecteuler.net/problems). Если с английским совсем туго, то можно подсматривать [перевод](http://euler.jakumo.org/problems/).

Comment: Вы должны уметь правильно работать с `std::string` так, чтобы не было потерь по производительности. «Со строками медленнее» — это даже не отмазка, это признание в незнании языка. Выучите, что такое ссылка в C++, и никогда больше не говорите, что `std::string` медленнее (а то и правда не возьмут даже джуниором).

Answer (score 0):

Проходил тот же тест, дошёл ло туда же. Как я понимаю, неожиданность в том, что заявлено, что будет введено 10 строк, а вводится одна. Что делать - неясно. Если выдавать сообщение об ошибке, то неясно, какое.
Вы не знаете, как же это всё-таки решается? Или как спросить решение у самого Яндекса?

Comment: Нет. Дают 10 строк, там же тест открыт. Если бы дали 1 строку, то и выдавать надо одну строку. А проблема тут в другом. 
Вот пример теста, который не прошел бы с моей(думаю с вашей тоже) программой: 
aaaadcq
dcaaaa
adc 

Моя программа сравнит первые 2 строки, и возьмет оттуда наибольшую, т.е. аааа. 
А ответ программа выдаст "а". Хотя правильный "dc". Суть того теста в этом же. 
------------
Решение же данной задачи кроется в построении суффиксального автомата. .

Comment: А как понять, что дали одну строку? Судя по тому, что написано в pdf-ке с описанием условий к заданиям, строки вводятся с клавиатуры. Тогда представьте себе: некто запускает ваш код, вводит 10, и должен бы ввести 10 строк, а вводит одну. Как узнать, что он никогда и не введёт остальные, а не тормозит с их вводом?
А суффиксное дерево, которое, как мне кажется, вы имеете в виду, обходится быстро, но места в памяти оно съедает,по-моему, не меньше, чем таблица, которую строит наивный алгоритм.

Comment: А так можно? Правда, это не совсем C++ (или совсем не C++):

    import Control.Monad
    import Data.List
    import qualified Data.Set as Set
    f w = let (o, n) = foldl (\(o, n) e -> (o ++ n, [e]:map (e:) n)) ([], []) w in Set.fromList (o++n)
    main = do
      s <- (map f . words) `fmap` getLine
      when (s == []) (fail "empty list")
      let r = foldl1 Set.intersection s
      let l = head $ groupBy (\a b -> fst a == fst b) $ sortBy (flip compare) $ map (\x -> (length x, x)) $ Set.toList r
      forM_ l (\(a, b) -> putStrLn $ reverse b)

Comment: Я не знаю, что это. А даже если бы и знал, я не Яндекс, и не могу ответить, можно ли так ;-)

Comment: Что-то меня заинтересовало в этой задаче. 

Реализовал на Си свой примитивный вариант с индексированием пар символов для каждой строки и тупым сравнением подстрок.

Получилась программа в 200 строк. Попробовал с указанным ТС тестом

    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out <mxcom.test 
    max common substr: [ibm] 3 bytes (pos 60 in line 0)
    time 10000 clocks (0.010000 sec)
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ grep CPU /proc/cpuinfo | tail -1
    model name : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz

Собственно 2 вопроса:

1. Это правильный ответ?

2. Какое время считается приемлимым?

Comment: Насчёт Яндекса -- вряд ли. А так -- это текст на haskell. Запустить можно, установив hugs, а далее -- runhugs andrw.hs (в andrw.hs -- приведённый текст)

Comment: @avp, на каждый тест дается по 1 секунде. 
Вы супер, мне о таком лишь мечтать.

Answer (score 0):

Да, если программа на haskell'е проходит каждый тест не больше, чем за секунду, это круто. Если она решает поставленную задачу - тоже. Но задача была из отборочного теста по C/C++

Comment: По приведённой ТС ссылке есть программа на haskell, где используются только списки, но сравнивать скорость работы мне лениво.

Comment: @alexlz, а если все-таки набрать `time runhugs andrw.hs < TC.test`, то каков результат?

Comment: @avp

    alex@ubuntu:~/tmp$ ghc -O2 --make andrw.hs
    alex@ubuntu:~/tmp$ cat >TC.txt
    aaaadcq dcaaaa adc
    alex@ubuntu:~/tmp$ time runhugs andrw.hs <TC.txt
    dc

    real 0m1.001s
    user 0m0.368s
    sys 0m0.112s
    alex@ubuntu:~/tmp$ time ./andrw <TC.txt
    dc

    real 0m0.173s
    user 0m0.004s
    sys 0m0.008s

Т.е. для hugs (вместе с трансляцией) -- более секунды. Оттранслированная ghc -- поменьше.

Comment: Отличный результат (по времени).

Но правильный ответ: **`ibm`**

Comment: Дубовый подход с генерацией всех возможных подстрок на строках 10K? Это утопия, бред, белая горячка (нужное подчеркнуть)

Comment: Почему? Это наивно и, скорее всего, медленно, но почему бред?